# Javascript OOP, Accessing methods from other nested methods

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, scope, phaser-framework

Ok, folks, getting there with learning my JS.
I have come across a singular one.
Here's the code:

```js
hangar = function(game){
}

hangar.prototype = {
  
  loadImages: function(graphicAssets){
    ...
  },
  
  writeTerminal: function(timer, str, destination){
  },
  
  writeStats: function(){
    var writeTerminal = this.writeTerminal;
    console.log('wt', this.writeTerminal);
    console.log('wt2', writeTerminal);
    //ZOMG This does not work!
  },
    
  handleHangarInput: function(layerShips, layerBg){
    
    ... does some variable declarations of which one is:
    
    var writeStats = this.writeStats;
    
    function viewHangarPosition() {
      
      writeStats(); // This works
      
    }
    
    keyleft.onDown.add(function(){
        
        if (currentship > 0) {
            currentship--;
            viewHangarPosition();
        }
    });

    keyright.onDown.add(function(){
        
        if (currentship < shipNumber-1) {
            currentship++;
            viewHangarPosition();
        }
    });

  }
  create: function(){
      this.handleHangarInput(layerShips, layerBg);
  }
    
}
```

here is where it's all called (index.html):

```js
        window.onload = function() {

            var game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update:update });

            function preload() {
            }

            function create() {
                game.state.add('menu', menu);
                game.state.add('hangar', hangar);
                game.state.start('hangar');
            }

            function update() {
            }
            
        }
```

I am trying to get hold of **writeTerminal** from within **writeStats**, which is not working for me.

- ***How is this done***?
- Is there a **smarter way** to use writeStats instead of declaring it inside **handleHangarInput**?

Still not a pro in closures and Scoping.
As always appreciate your help!

Edited with further code

Here's the revised code:

```js
hangar = function(game){
}

hangar.prototype = {
  
  loadImages: function(graphicAssets){
    ...
  },
  
  writeTerminal: function(timer, str, destination){
  },
  
  writeStats: function(){
      console.log(this); // returns undefined
      console.log(this.writeTerminal); // errors out!
  },
    
  handleHangarInput: function(layerShips, layerBg){
    
    ... does some variable declarations of which one is:
    
    var writeStats = this.writeStats;
    
    function viewHangarPosition() {
      
      writeStats.call(this);
      
    }
    
    keyleft.onDown.add(function(){
        
        if (currentship > 0) {
            currentship--;
            viewHangarPosition();
        }
    });

    keyright.onDown.add(function(){
        
        if (currentship < shipNumber-1) {
            currentship++;
            viewHangarPosition();
        }
    });

  }
  create: function(){
      this.handleHangarInput(layerShips, layerBg);
  }
    
}
```

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how the function is called, and within `viewHangarPosition` the window will probably be the calling scope depending on how `viewHangarPosition` is called ?

Comment: I've just updated the code snippet so you can see how everything is called.

Comment: I still don't see any calls to `viewHangarPosition()` ?

Comment: added, apologies.
I'm thinking of passing (this) to the nameless function on the keyhandler now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/476

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has *calltime* binding of the `this` keyword. I.e., what `this` refers to in a function depends on how exactly that function was *called* (not how it was defined). In a nutshell: `this` refers to the object the method was called on.

```
foo.bar();
```

Here inside `bar` the keyword `this` will refer to `foo`.

```
bar();
```

Here inside `bar` the keyword `this` will not refer to anything in particular, so defaults to the global object `window`.

```
var bar = foo.bar;
bar();
```

Same as above (`window`), because of how the function was called.

If you want to reassign object methods yet still keep their context at call time, you need to handle this explicitly:

```
var bar = foo.bar.bind(foo);
bar();

// or:
var bar = foo.bar();
bar.call(foo);
```

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand.
I've done as you said so basically I bound **hangar** to it writeStats so it then would be able to call this.writeTerminal.

    writeStats.call(hangar)

inside writeStats then I log(this) and I do get the hangar object, but it still runs undefined when I try to then run this.writeTerminal.

Comment: Calltime binding can be a bit of a brain bender, since it's an unusual feature. But it's pretty simple once you know it exists. Javascript really only has two significant parts to it: objects and functions. Both have very few rules, and everything else follows from that. If you're used to classical inheritance, simply forget about it. ;)

Comment: You would have to update your code with the revised version for me to be able to say anything specifically. (Please don't overwrite your existing code though, that'd invalidate the question's context.)

Comment: You need to call `writeStats.call(this)`. `hangar` doesn't have a `writeTerminal` method, only its prototype does.

Comment: Ok I feel like a real noob again.
I thought that extending it via prototype it WOULD have gained those methods.

Still I don't understand what I'm passing in with "this" in this case: the prototype?

Actually it still **doesn't work** passing "this".

Comment: Err... okay, *three* significant parts... ;) When you *instantiate* an object with `new`, it gets the methods of its *constructors* `prototype` added to its `__proto__` chain. Only the `__proto__` attribute is used for looking up missing methods/inheriting methods. So, your `new` objects will have those methods, your constructor does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76454/discussion-between-grumpygamer-and-deceze).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what your asking, but when you call:

```
writeStats();
```

as it is done in the viewHangarPosition, since you are not applying the function to any object, it's the window object that is passed to writeStats() as the this object. So in writeStats, this.writeTerminal will be undefined.