# confusing bind. how to bind an object to another?

Tags: javascript

in this code,

```
var person = {
  first: 'person',
  last: 'sdfsd',
  full: function fullName() {return this.first +  ' ' + this.last;}
}

var john = {
    first:  'person',
    last : 'sdfsd'
}
```

how do I bind john to person such that something like

```
var Name = john.bind(person)
```

can call:

```
Name.full();
```

tried couple of things and getting:
this.full is not a function OR
Name.full is not a function;

I also want to understand whether bind can be used on objects like above or the object has to be a   function object to use bind upon?

**UPDATE**

When I do this:

```
var person = {
  first: 'person',
  last: 'sdfsd',
  full: function fullName() {console.log(this.first +  ' ' + this.last);}
}

var john = {
    first:  'john',
    last : 'sdfsd',
  fl: function() {return this.full();}
}

var Name = person.full.bind(john);

Name();
```

I get

```
john sdfsd
```

So I infer:

- bind works only on functions. Is that correct?
- I thought that if I bind like `var Name = john.fl.bind(person);` then ***this*** would be, upon calling `Name();`, person and call `console.log(person.first +  ' ' + person.last);` but instead I had to swap the 2 to get the right output. Could someone tell me what gets bound to what? in x.bind(y)??

---

**UPDATE 2**
A little bit of .bind function that Ive understood:

If I create something like this:

```
var jane = function (first, last) {
  if (first) {this.first = first;}
  if (last) {this.last = last;}
  return this.full();
}
```

And bind it to person fellow above:

```
var janeName = jane.bind(person);
janeName();
```

I get:

```
person sdfsd
```

in the console. However, the root of my problem was to get the first and last vars defined in Jane, if I would optionally:

```
janeName.call(jane, 'jane', 'austen');
```

this returns:

```
jane austen
```

Correct me if I am wrong. How this works is janeName is as usual, jane, but the **this** is bound to Person.
BUT, calling with .call janeName is jane bound to person with optional args provided, here actually ***jane*** calls itself, with optional args provided, but in turn is bound to ***person*** as well, when looking up for **.full** function.

Comment: `bind` is used to change context of a `function`. `person.full.bind(john)` is what you are looking for

Comment: @Tushar  so bind cannot be used with a 'non'-function object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
john.full = person.full;
var name = john.full();
```

The `bind` way would look like this:

```
var name = person.full.call(john);  // call the full() function using john as context

var getName = person.full.bind(john);  // create a function to get the full name from john
var name = getName();
```

Comment: deceze ive added an update because with the solution you proposed, it is confusing me what caller is the bound to which function object.

Comment: Javascript's funky part is that the value of `this` inside a function is determined by how the function is called. `bind`, `call` and `apply` only influence this specific part, setting the value of `this` for a function. Once you get that, it should make sense.

Comment: your statement implies dynamic scoping. i understand that. What i dont understand is bind and henceforth call/apply. Ive updated the question

Comment: It really is as simple as this: Javascript decides *at call time* what `this` refers to inside the called function. Nothing more, nothing less. "Dynamic scopes" and whatnot is too difficult a way to think of it. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29917797/476 It's a mind blowingly simple mechanism, yet very unusual if you don't know it.

Comment: what you described there is called dynamic scoping. i understood binding as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31539703/2290820

Comment: It's loosely related to dynamic scoping at best, which is why it's unproductive to think in these terms IMO. *Scoping* in Javascript is lexical. The behaviour of `this` has not much to do with "scope". `this` is a "magic" variable which will reference different objects. It's no more or less about scoping than the `arguments` magic variable is.

Answer (score 0):

To set this to a variable that you can reference when you change context.

### To Know More Detail bout Bind:

[Click Here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/)

So it must be

Here we set our john context to the Person. based on this it return the Context of John

```js
 var person = {
      first: 'tatdsfds',
      last: 'sdfsd',
      full: function fullName() {
         document.write("content: "+this.first +  " " + this.last);
        return this.first +  ' ' + this.last;}
    }
    
    var john = {
        first:  'John',
        last : 'Mr'
    }
    
    var Name = person.full.bind(john); //set our john context to the Person
    
    Name();
```

Comment: "TypeError: john.bind is not a function
    at <anonymous>:20:17
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understood bind a little more clearly.
Instead of thinking it in terms of class based method call **.bind()**
, thinking in terms of dynamically scoped, in terms of **this**, and where *this* would bind to **which** function to produce **what** output:

```
var person = {
  first: 'person',
  last: 'sdfsd',
  full: function fullName() {console.log(this.first +  ' ' + this.last);}
}

var john = {
    first:  'john',
    last : 'sdfsd',
  fl: function() {return this.full();}
}
```

If I want john's output of first and last:

```
john sdfsd
```

the function that does that here is in Person, called ***full*** ;

If I bind ***full*** function to john, ***this*** refer's to john.

```
var Name = person.full.bind(john);

Name();
```

Similarly,

if I want ***person's output***

```
john.fl.call(person);
```

I will have to bind john.fl to be **call**ed by person. Here,

`this.full();` in ***john.fl*** is called by ***person*** => `person.full()`